# How do I donate my shares to the company?

Tags: stocks, donation

In *The Interpretation of Financial Statements* by Benjamin Graham, Part III *Definitions of Terms*:

> *Treasury Stock*. Lawfully issued stock that has been reacquired by the corporation through purchase or donation.

The book appears to be published in 1935. Nowadays, is it still possible to donate stock to the company? If so, what is the process like?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish by making the donation?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible somehow to give your shares back to the company, but are you wondering if there's an associated tax benefit?

Comment: @DStanley I'm just wondering if it is possible. Not that I want to do it. I just want to know the process.

Comment: I could see doing this in a closely held private company. For example if your spouse is the only other shareholder.

Comment: You see this from time to time on 10-Ks but seems uncommon. Is this just a curiosity sort of question or is there a problem you're trying to solve?